# What do you call the elements of a module?

Tags: python, module

I have this code from Learn Python The Hard Way and I need to comment it:

```
from sys import argv
```

So I did: #imports argv from the sys module

I know what argv does, but I am having trouble figuring out what to call this element of the sys module? A variable, a method, a function? Argument variable?

Also, given that line of code, does it mean that all the sys module is imported in my program or only argv?

Comment: When learning, or when writing a tutorial, that is ok. But normally it is better to comment *why* you do something and not *what* you do - that is visible from the code.

Comment: @glglgl Good observation! I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argv` is a variable in the `sys` module's namespace. It happens to be a list.

The statement

```
from sys import argv
```

causes Python to parse the entire `sys` module (assuming it has not already been parsed, in which case it is *not* reloaded), and copy the `argv` variable into the current module's namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> I know what argv does, but I am having trouble figuring out how to call this element of the sys module?

I think you mean ***what*** to call argv, not how to call it.  It isn't callable.  Here's how you prove that in python.

```
>>> import sys
>>> callable(sys.argv)
False
```

Now, as unutbu mentioned above the sys module is loaded, assuming it has not already been loaded.  What does this mean?  Well when you import a module it's added to a dictionary in sys called sys.modules.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.modules.keys
['copy_reg', 'encodings', 'site', '__builtin__', '__main__', 'encodings.encodings', 'abc', 'posixpath', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', '_abcoll', 'types', '_codecs', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport', 'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.utf_8', 'sys', 'codecs', 'readline', 'os.path', 'signal', 'linecache', 'posix', 'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'os']
```

The dictionary sys.modules prevents the module from being reloaded.  The import statement checks sys.modules to prevent the module from being reloaded.

If you really are into module mayhem, take a look at the list sys.builtin_module_names.

If you're hacking on a script and want to effect the changes immediately in the interpreter, then reload the script.

```
>>> reload(sys)
>>> help(reload)
Help on built-in function reload in module __builtin__:

reload(...)
    reload(module) -> module

    Reload the module.  The module must have been successfully imported before.
```

So there you have more than you ever wanted to know about modules and module attributes :D.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html talks about

> definitions from a module can be *imported* into other modules or into the *main* module

and further below

> There is a variant of the `import` statement that imports names from a module directly into the importing module’s symbol table.

In this sense, `argv` is a name which is defined in `sys`.